# Run MySql query on all ids in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have this query that gives me the last transaction date, first name, and last name of a Client in my DB. Let say I want to find the last transaction date of client 13423 this is the query:

```
SELECT LastTransactionDate AS was_last_seen,
(SELECT DISTINCT(FirstName) FROM Clients WHERE PmsId=13423) AS FirstName, 
(SELECT DISTINCT(LastName) FROM Clients WHERE PmsId=13423) AS LastName
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT(pa.PmsId),pa.LastTransactionDate,cpr.ClientPmsId
    FROM Patients AS pa RIGHT JOIN ClientPatientRelationships AS cpr ON 
    pa.PmsId=cpr.PatientPmsId WHERE cpr.ClientPmsId = 13423
) AS result ORDER BY LastTransactionDate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Now I want to run this on every client in the Clients Table.

I can find a list of all clients using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PmsId) AS distinct_clients FROM Clients;
```

I'm new to SQL is there anyway that I can run this on all clients? I would love to do that in a single query, but I'm not sure its possible.

I also tried using a SP with a cursor, but for some reason the cursor was fetching two results for each PmsId, but my SELECT DISTINCT(PmsId) query returns a list of DISTINCT ids, so not sure how the cursor was running a single PmsId through the main query twice.

Also the cursor was SUPER slow ,it times out after running 6mins, which is weird because I only have about 14,000 clients, and the above query I'm using runs in less that a second on a single client.

I'm wondering if I should try to do this in PHP? Or would that be bad practice?

Let me know if this makes any sense

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max(b.LastTransactionDate)` and `group by a.ClientPmsId` to find the `LastTransactionDate` for every client, then join it to the `Clients` table to get the first and last name.

```
select a.PmsId, a.FirstName, a.LastName, b.LastTransactionDate
from (select PmsId, FirstName, LastName
    from Clients
    group by PmsId) a
left join (select a.ClientPmsId, max(b.LastTransactionDate) LastTransactionDate
    from ClientPatientRelationships a
    join Patients b on a.PatientPmsId = b.PmsId
    group by a.ClientPmsId) b on a.PmsId = b.ClientPmsId;
```

Comment: You sir, just saved my day. Thank you so much!! This really helps and gives me what I need :)